# Stop SoundManager 2 playback on close of Colorbox window?

Tags: jquery, colorbox, soundmanager2

I have instance of SoundManager 2 setup as inline HTML that displays a list of songs within a Colorbox window.  Everything is good until I close the Colorbox window. The sound continues unless I reopen the window and stop it manually. My thought was to use the `onCleanup` callback with the `soundManager.stopAll();` method so the sound stops as soon as the window begins to close. But because my Jquery skills are that of a beginner I'm not sure of the proper placement or syntax. I'm currently calling my colorbox windows with the basic syntax of:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".inlinePlayer1").colorbox({inline:true, width:"300px",height:"530px"});
        $(".inlinePlayer2").colorbox({inline:true, width:"300px",height:"550px"});
    });
```